# How to use Jinja2 inside configs?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have this code:

```
{{ config (
    materialized = 'incremental',
    properties = {
        "location": "'s3://iceberg/table_{{trigger.run_started_at}}'
    }
```

The `{{trigger.run_started_at}}` doesn't seem to work and it stays as it is.

I need to get something like this:

```
's3://iceberg/table_2023-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research and experimentation, I figured out that it's not possible. Nevertheless, this can be done:

```
{% set location = "'s3://iceberg_test/my_table_" ~ run_started_at ~ "'" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't be nesting double curlies. Does this not work?

```
{{ config (
    materialized = 'incremental',
    properties = "location": "'s3://iceberg_test/my_table_" ~ run_started_at ~ "'"
}}
```

If so, you can use macros in the config. So you can use something like env_var() or any custom macro. You wouldn't use double curly braces or anything to call it.

```
{{ config (
    materialized = 'incremental',
    properties = get_location()
}}
```

You could then write the macro to return the expected data-type (map/dict)